# change rails app from webrick to passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, webrick

Need some help moving a rails app from webrick to passenger with apache. Im very new to all this and i cant get it running with passenger. I have tried a bunch of guides and I am not getting any errors apart from the rails server always using webrick instead of passenger. I am working on mac mini OSX as server

I seen that osx comes with a version of mac already installed but i read online that i should load a newer copy so i make sure that the currently installed apache is not running in system preferences/sharing/web sharing.

then i `brew install apachetop`. followed by `gem install passenger` and `passenger-install-apache2-module` .

I then follow the instructions from passenger in terminal which asks me to place some code in the httpd.conf file. which i find in /ect/apache2 from root.

I then add the virtual host info to the apache config file too where /public/mom is location of my rails app.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost:3000
    DocumentRoot /public/mom
    RailsEnv development 
    <Directory /public/mom>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I then make sure apache is running with sudo apachectl start and try running my rails server but it still runs using webrick.

I have seen posts saying that i need to make sure that passenger is installing with the correct version of apache that i installed. how do i force passenger to install with the apache i installed rather then default? am i ment to be naming the servername within the config file as localhost? Can anyone give me some guidance on how to get the rails app running with passenger . maybe i missed some steps or misunderstood the process completely. thanks

edit: below is apache error_log

```
    [Wed Jul 20 19:17:01 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using mini.local for ServerName
[Wed Jul 20 19:17:02 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 20 19:17:02 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 20 19:17:02 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 20 19:17:22 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 20 19:39:32 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using mini.local for ServerName
[Wed Jul 20 19:39:45 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 20 19:39:45 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 20 19:39:45 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 20 19:43:33 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jul 20 20:09:35 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Warning: DocumentRoot [/public/mom] does not exist
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using mini.local for ServerName
[Wed Jul 20 20:09:35 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 20 20:09:35 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 20 20:09:35 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 21 10:36:59 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "try running my rails server". How do you run your rails server?

Comment: i go into the folder that contains the rails project which in my case is public/mom in terminal and i enter rails server to start it up.

Comment: AFAIK that is now how Passenger works. You have to start Apache and then go to the URL of the vhost you configured. Then Passenger itself starts the Rails application on the first request.

Comment: Of course I meant "this is NOT how"

Comment: yeah figured u ment not :P . ok then without running rails server and restarting apache and going to the url it just tells me cannot connect to server. so i must have done somthing wrong with apache itself. how do i know which version of apache im running? as in how does sudo apachectl start know which apache to run. and does default apache and the apache i installed with brew have dif config files and any ideas how to find them? maybe i have been using wrong config file

Answer (score 0):

"try running my rails server but it still runs using webrick", seems your webrick is still active.

```
lsof -i -P |grep 3000
kill -9 WEBRICK_PID
```

Comment: yeah i tried that too but didnt help. must be something im doing wrong with passenger and apache.

Comment: what's page headers of pages served from that webserver?

Comment: got it working in the end with nginx instead of apache. no idea what i was doing wrong with apache. something simple and stupid im sure but nginx worked straight away. thanks anyway

Comment: nginx works fastet, better and takes less memory. Good choice!